# Send Email Verification Firebase Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm newbie at Firebase
can anyone give me a reference or example for sending email verification from Firebase in java.

i already can make an custom token but i get confuse how to send email verification for related user that already got custom token

Comment: In Android, after authenticating the user  with the custom token and setting the user's email, you can use this function to send the verification email: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Comment: @Gerardo ty for ur comment guys, but actually i try to find in java as rest api way can help me?